# How do I use Flask-Login with an SPA?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to create a Python/Flask/Vue/Vuetify web app, and to keep it simpler to manage the CSS/styling I want there to be only a single 'page' served by my back-end, which is the SPA (single-page app).  I don't want to have Flask serving a separate 'login' page, 'register' page, etc.  Just serve the SPA and have the user directed to different views within the SPA depending on whether they're logged out, registering, logged in, etc.

How do I implement a login/logout process with Flask-Login like this?